# Firebase auth() succeeded, but my security rules that check for logged-in state still fail

Tags: firebase

When I use `".read": "auth != null"`, `ref.on()` raises a permission error after `ref.auth()` completed without error. What's the proper way to grant read permission as long as the user is logged in?

Security rule:

```
{
  "rules": { 
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth.admin == true"
  }
}
```

Here's the code that returns me a Firebase ref before I perform "on()" on it:

```
    ref: function(path) { var self = this;
      var ref = new Firebase(self.url + path);
      ref.auth(self.auth_token, function(err) {
        if (err && console) console.log("Firebase "+path+" login failed!");
        else if (console) console.log("Firebase "+path+" login succeeded.");
      });
      return ref;
    },
    bind: function(path, excludes) { var self = this;
      var collection = [];
      var ref = self.ref(path);
      ...
      var move_callback = function(data, prevId) { 
        $timeout(function() { moveItem(data, prevId); }); 
      }
      ref.on('child_added', move_callback);
      ref.on('child_changed', move_callback);
      ref.on('child_moved', move_callback);
      ref.on('child_removed', function(data) {
        $timeout(function() { removeItem(data); });
      });
      return collection;
    },
```

MAIN controller:

```
$scope.list = $$firebase.bind("/data", []);
```

Console says

```
Firebase /data login succeeded. app.js:298
FIREBASE WARNING: on() or once() for /data failed: permission_denied firebase.js:33
```

Comment: re: 3 - can you share your security rules, and show what path you're trying to perform `ref.on` against, so we can analyze?

Comment: that ".read" is fine; it's not causing your error. On a side note, your "question" now comprises 3 very distinct discussions: filtering, querying a list vs a hash, and finally troubleshooting a permissions error.

Comment: Okay, so this looks like the correct way to grant read permissions. I'd suspect it's the .write that's the culprit, or that the auth hasn't actually succeeded. Did you go into Forge and try the "simulator"? That might provide some useful clues.

Comment: As Kato mentioned, the rules look correct. Can you share your code snippet as well? Also - try the simulate, and make sure you're using the correct URL for your Firebase!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me from your code that you are returning the reference after auth has completed. Specifically:

```js
ref: function(path) {
  var self = this;
  var ref = new Firebase(self.url + path);
  ref.auth(self.auth_token, function(err) {
    if (err && console) console.log("Firebase "+path+" login failed!");
    else if (console) console.log("Firebase "+path+" login succeeded.");
  });
  return ref;
}
```

is returning the reference immediately. The callback to auth is asynchronous, so if you're using your ref before the callback is called your session will be unauthenticated.

It looks like you are using Angular, so I whipped a small example, which worked correctly with the same security rules as you: https://gist.github.com/anantn/5304404

If I were to rewrite your code, I would do it as follows:

```js
bind: function(path) {
  var ref = new Firebase(self.url + path);
  var d = self._q.defer(); // Assign $q to this._q in constructor.
  ref.auth(self.auth_token, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      ref.once("value", function(snap) {
        d.resolve(snap.val());
      });
    }
  });
  return d.promise;
}
...
// In the controller:
$scope.list = $$firebase.bind("/data");
```

I highly recommend using promises via the $q module to ensure you don't use the Firebase reference before the auth has completed. An even better solution would be to use the official  Firebase bindings for Angular that already takes care of all this for you: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I need an instance of the "authed" ref. How do I get that?

Comment: The same ref is authenticated after the callback to ref.auth has been invoked with the first argument as 'null'. Thus, to obtain an instance of the authed ref, just make sure to put any code that expects it inside the if (!err) block of the callback.